# I thought i fixed it yesterday but i messed up, it still generates the same random number

Tags: c

So i thought i fixed this yesterday when you guys answered my question, but today i realized that i forgot that i disabled the function named bubbleSort(), once i enabled that function the addRandomNumbers() function directly below main started generating the same number as the random number instead of different numbers again, even though i seeded the generator once at program start. It only generates different random numbers if i disable the bubbleSort() function which is weird because thats an entirely different function.
But i kind of need the bubble sort function  so that the binarySearch() function im going to make will work

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 

#define clear       system("cls") 
#define pause       system("pause") 
#define SIZE        5000
#define LB          1    //this is the lower bound
#define UB          500  //this is the upper bound


//Lets Prototype
void addRandomNumbers(int n[]);
void binarySearch(int n[],int c[]);
void bubbleSort(int n[]);
void displayRandomNumbers(int n[],int c[]);

int main(){
    int numbers[SIZE]={0}, counter[SIZE]={0};
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    addRandomNumbers(numbers);
    bubbleSort(numbers); 
    binarySearch(numbers,counter);
    displayRandomNumbers(numbers,counter);

}//end main

void addRandomNumbers(int n[]){
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < SIZE; i++){
    n[i] = LB + rand() % (UB - LB + 1 );
    }
}//end addRandomNumbers

void bubbleSort(int n[]){
    int i,temp=0;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE-1;i++){
        temp=n[i];
        n[0]=n[1];
        n[i+1]=temp;
    }//end for loop
}//end bubble sort

void binarySearch(int n[],int c[]){
    int i,k=0,l,u,mid;


    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){

       l=0,u=SIZE-1;
       while(l<=u){
            mid=(l+u)/2;
            if(n[i]==n[mid]){
                k++;
                break;
            }
            else if(n[i]<n[mid]){
                u=mid-1;
            }
            else
                l=mid+1; 
       }//end while loop
       c[i]=k;
    }//end for loop
}

void displayRandomNumbers(int n[], int c[]){
    int i; 
    char flag;
    for(i=0;i<UB;i++)
        if(c[i]<100)    
        printf("The number %i appears %i times\n",n[i],c[i]);
        pause;
}//end displayRandomNumbers
```

Comment: Your bubblesort function fills the array with first element. And the has buffer overflow by 1...

Comment: Where is `<stdlib.h>` and `<time.h>` and other headers?

Comment: What platform are you running this on?  What output does it give?

Comment: oh sorry <stdlib.h> and <time.h> etc is above i forgot to paste it. Im running on visual studios 2012 and i get an output of "It is *1  random number*"

Comment: But on my compiler it is working fine.

Comment: really what compiler are you using. By the way the output i get displays the same random number 500 times

Comment: I am using GCC 4.8.1.

Comment: See the outputs here. Two different out puts [1](http://ideone.com/mOCTsw). [2](http://ideone.com/y8FRjx). I removed `counter` array and removed one parameter from your function `displayRandomNumbers` (they were useless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your so-called `bubbleSort` that's actually not at all an implementation of bubble sort that fills your array with the same number, in a convoluted way. (How could it possibly be a sort function if it doesn't ever compare values of the array?)

Why don't you use the C standard library `qsort` function if you don't know how to properly implement a sort algorithm?

Comment: thanks.. my professor actually gave us that bubble sort algorithm because he thought he wouldnt be able to make one at our level yet... but i'll look up qsort. Glad to know the issue isnt seeding the time though

Answer (score 1):

I think you are seeing the same numbers as displayed output *probabilistically.*

If I can summarize your program, you:

1. fill a 5000-length array with numbers between LB (1) and UB (500) (`addRandomNumbers` function)
2. sort the array (`bubbleSort` function)
3. print the FIRST element (`displayRandomNumbers` function).

Let's assume your sort function works.  The first element of the sorted array will be `1` if that value was sampled for *any* of the 5000 numbers.  It could be `2` if there were no values of `1` selected, could also be `3`, etc.

What is the probability that you would observe a `2` or greater number as the first element of the array?  It is the probability that ZERO values of `1` were sampled.  Assuming uniform probability (which your sampling method does not provide):

`p(zero observations of 1) = (499 / 500) ^ (5000) = 0.00005`

In other words, it is very likely that your unsorted array will contain a value of `1` *somewhere*.  When you sort it, that value will become the first element of the array.

Comment: I actually just posted the same code as my last question because i thought i only had to change one thing to show you guys the issue i had at hand but i updated the question with my current code because i realized too much changed to use that old code

Comment: Okay, it sounds like you described a problem your program exhibits, and posted code for an /old/ version of that program.  My answer was written with the original version of your question.

Comment: i know it was, thats what i commented to tell you. Last time i messed up on something i posted a new question for it people got mad at me and told me to change it on the original question. I guess theres no right way to do it then

Comment: Here is my suggestion:  as Rord's pointed out, your BubbleSort function should not work.  Change the size of your array to 8, and try in a separate program testing your version of `bubbleSort` with input and output that you can print out.  When troubleshooting, it's best to tackle one problem at a time.  Otherwise, if you keep building your program with a broken version of `bubbleSort`, you are building on a shaky foundation.

Comment: that sounds like a good idea it will be alot easier to troubleshoot with a size of 8, im definitely going to try to fix bubble sort first too thanks